# calculate $P(|X-E[X]|<2(Var[X])^{0.5})$ probability

Tags: probability, variance

Let there be $0< \epsilon \leq 1$ and let there be $X$ a random variable that acts in the following way:

$P(x=1) = P(x = -1) = (\epsilon^2)/2$, $P(x=0) = 1-\epsilon^2$

**Calculate: $P(|X-E[x]|<2(Var[X])^{0.5})$**

So we can either calculate by hand or claim that the distribution is symmetric around $0$

So $E[X] = 0$.

$Var(X) = \sigma^2 =\sum X^2P(x)-0 = \epsilon^2$ and therefore $\sigma = \epsilon$

Now I'm kind of stuck. How to proceed from here? In other words I need to calculate $P(|X|<2\sigma)$

Whereas $0< \epsilon \leq 1$

There's a photo with a better-looking explanation
[PHOTO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mfkrc.png)

Comment: The set $\{|X|<2\sigma\}$ is the same as $A=\{-2\sigma<X<2\sigma\}$. If $\epsilon\geq1/2$ then $\{-1,0,1\}\subset[-1,1]\subset A$. Since $P(\{-1,0,1\})=1$ then $P(A)=1$ too.

Comment: If $\epsilon < 1/2$, then $0\in A$ but $-1,1\notin A$. Before computing prove that $P(B)=0$ for any set that doesn't contain $-1,0,1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$|X| = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{ w. p. } \epsilon^2 \\ 0  & \text{w.p. } 1-\epsilon^2\end{cases}$$

$$P(|X| < 2 \epsilon)=\begin{cases} 1 & ,\epsilon > \frac12  \\ 1-\epsilon^2  & , \epsilon\leq \frac12\end{cases}$$

Explanation:

If $\epsilon > \frac12$, $2 \epsilon > 1 \geq |X|.$

If $0 <\epsilon \leq \frac12$, $0 < 2\epsilon < 1$, only $|X|=0$ satisfies the condition.